# rails: Scheduled jobs but run at most one at single time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks

I have the scheduled job which run every 5 seconds. I'm now using backgroudRB for scheduling. But sometimes, the job may take more than 5 seconds and i don't want more than one job is running at the same time. In .Net, we can use Mutex class, but I'm not sure about what should I use in rails application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck, I remember using backgrounDRb, it was horrible.  I use Resque now, after using delayed_job.  Both work well, and you can solve your problem by only running a single worker.  You can find both on Github.